# Ava doesn't know to import .jsx dependencies from source files used in tests

Tags: javascript, jsx, ava

I have the following ava config in my package.json:

```
{
"ava": {
    "require": [
      "./tests/helpers/setup-browser-env.js",
      "./tests/helpers/module-stubber.js",
      "babel-register"
    ],
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0",
        "react"
      ]
    },
    "failFast": true,
    "verbose": false,
    "no-cache": false,
    "concurrency": 5
  }
}
```

and I have the following project structure:

```
src
  index.jsx
  components
      input.jsx
tests
  index.test.js
```

**index.jsx**

```
import Input from './components/input';

console.log(Input);
```

**input.jsx**

```
import react from 'react';

export default () => <input></input>;
```

**input.test.js**

```
import app from '../src';
// ...
```

The problem is that ava is able to transpile my `src/index.jsx` file but it doesn't transpile `input.jsx` and I am seing an empty object logged in my console. It only works if I import the component using the `.jsx` extension like so: **import Input from './component/input.jsx**. I can't make it to work without specifying the extension.

Is this possible in AVA? In Webpack it is a simple config which handles these kinds of patterns.

Looking in the ava docs under the configuration section: https://github.com/avajs/ava#configuration I can't see any field which can help me. (also the config fields don't seem to be really detailed).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dowvoter I'm waiting for a description

Answer (score 1):

`babel-register` is in charge of requiring `input.jsx`, not AVA. It's surprising that importing from `../src` works, but importing `input` does not. I don't really have an answer for you though.